# 'topFunction' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: angularjs, typescript

in Angular project, i have given a function name called "topFunction" in my html page and written the function within the `ngOnit()` in `component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {

  function topFunction() {
    ...
  }

}
```

while hovering on the function name it shows me text "'topFunction' is declared but its value is never read.
(local function) topFunction(): void
"   that particular function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You only declared a function. Unless you call it, its code will never be executed and thus it is unused. Typescript warns you about unused locals (under `strict` or `noUnusedLocals`).

To call the function you should write

```
ngOnInit() {

  function topFunction() {
    ...
  }
  topFunction();
}
```

Or do something else with it such as assign it to a member or to an event handler.